# Have to press twice for Swift 3 button action

Tags: ios, button, swift3

I have two radio buttons, each with it's own `IBAction`. The first performs flawlessly. The second has an if-else condition and doesn't respond to the first tap but then responds to each tap thereafter. From looking at similar questions, I have sense that the first tap is just evaluating my function before performing the action but I am unable to figure out a way to get the button to respond on the first tap.

```
@IBAction func radioSchedule(_ sender: Any) {
         print(timePicker.isHidden)

        if timePicker.isHidden == true {

            timePicker.isHidden = false
            hideButton.isHidden = true
            timeView.isHidden = false
            itemTypeField.text = "Schedule"
            saveButton.isHidden = false

        } else {
            timePicker.isHidden = true
            timeView.isHidden = true
        }
        }
```

Comment: Are you seeing any output in the debug console from `print(timePicker.isHidden)` on the first tap?

Comment: Yes, I am.  The picker is hidden but the console says false...then true on the second tap when the picker comes up.

Comment: @JWHall ^ So, that is interesting. Let's evaluate that. It seems like the button is working fine... where/how are you initially setting `timePicker` as hidden?

Comment: Initially, I did this at the top of the viewDidLoad but I deleted that and the only references to timePicker.isHidden are as an outlet and then in the IBAction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is your `timePicker` sits inside your `timeView` and `timeView` is initially hidden, but your `timePicker` is not, and that is what is causing your issue.

If so, you could probably fix this by just judging your `if/else` off of your `timeView`, and then you wouldn't even have to worry about setting the `timePicker` to hidden or not.

i.e.:

```
@IBAction func radioSchedule(_ sender: Any) {

        print(timeView.isHidden)

        if timeView.isHidden {

            hideButton.isHidden = true
            timeView.isHidden = false
            itemTypeField.text = "Schedule"
            saveButton.isHidden = false

        } else {
            timeView.isHidden = true
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks William!  This fixed it.  Was the problem with my logic that I was trying to do two things with the same else block, that I was trying to do one thing inside another, or something else entirely?

Comment: No. Your problem was you were trying to judge off whether the `timePicker` was hidden or not, but `timePicker` was never hidden originally... only the view it sits in was hidden - `timeView`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like setting `timepicker.ishidden` is creating the problem modify your code something like this:-

```
@IBAction func radioSchedule(_ sender: Any) {
  print(timePicker.isHidden)
  //Here updating the isHidden property first. If its false then initially will set to true.
  timePicker.isHidden = !timePicker.isHidden
  if timePicker.isHidden == true {
    hideButton.isHidden = true
    timeView.isHidden = false
    itemTypeField.text = "Schedule"
    saveButton.isHidden = false
   } else {
        timeView.isHidden = true
      }
  }
```

Comment: Here the timePicker pops right up.  But the else condition never fires so I can't hide it on the second press.

Comment: This is just a hot fix. You need to explore why the `timepicker.isHidden` is printing false the first time, when you seem to believe it is already hidden